# Getting the status code from a get request in golang

Tags: http, go, url, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to get the http status code in goland.

I'm passing the authorization token as well.

This is what I tried so far:

```
func StatusCode(PAGE string, AUTH string) (r string){

    resp, err := http.NewRequest("GET", PAGE, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    resp.Header.Set("Authorization", AUTH)

    fmt.Println("HTTP Response Status:", resp.StatusCode, http.StatusText(resp.StatusCode))

    r := resp.StatusCode + http.StatusText(resp.StatusCode)
}
```

Basically I want to get this:

```
r = "200 OK"
or
r= "400 Bad request"
```

The previous code it´s complaining from **resp.StatusCode** and **http.StatusText(resp.StatusCode)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems.  The first is that the application uses the request as the response.  [Execute the request](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Client.Do) to get the response.

The second problem is that `resp.StatusCode + http.StatusText(resp.StatusCode)` does not compile because operand types are mismatched.  The value [`resp.StatusCode`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Response.StatusCode) is an `int`.  The value of [`http.StatusText(resp.StatusCode)`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#StatusText) is a `string`.  Go does not have the implicit conversion of numbers to strings that would make this work the way you expect.

Use `r := resp.Status` if you want the [status string as sent from the server](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Response.Status).

Use `r := fmt.Sprintf("%d %s", resp.StatusCode, http.StatusText(resp.StatusCode))` to construct a status string from the server's status code and the Go's status strings.

Here's the code:

```
func StatusCode(PAGE string, AUTH string) (r string) {
    // Setup the request.
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", PAGE, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    req.Header.Set("Authorization", AUTH)

    // Execute the request.
    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return err.Error()
    }
    
    // Close response body as required.
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    fmt.Println("HTTP Response Status:", resp.StatusCode, http.StatusText(resp.StatusCode))

    return resp.Status
    // or fmt.Sprintf("%d %s", resp.StatusCode, http.StatusText(resp.StatusCode))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Why my editor is complaining about resp.StatusCode. Packet is defined correctly. Http.NewRequest is fine here, isn’t?

Comment: May you please update the full code with the modifications that you think are correct in this case? I tried that but not working so i am not sure if i followed your suggestions correctly. Thanks.